# sed inside shell script not working

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, sed

I wrote the following shell script to delete the second line in a file, in this case: downloads.txt:

```
sed -e '2d' downloads.txt
```

This works in line but when inside a shell script it does not seem to work.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Obviously, the source code of your script would help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not seem to work'? Technically, the line `sed -e '2d' downloads.txt` does not delete the line in the file downloads.txt. It reads the downloads.txt into internal buffer, deletes the 2nd line and displays the buffer. And it works from CLI and from script.

Comment: Do you have an alias for `sed` that automatically includes the `-i` option when run from the command line? The alias would not be used in a script.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the fault is somewhere in the surroundings of what you have told us.  So either tell us more of that or search there for yourself.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs. it works now. Based on chepner's comment I switched -e to -i and it deleted the line from the file. Thank you for the great replies.

Comment: Please post an answer and mark it as accepted so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been solved. Please find solution below:

```
sed -i '2d' downloads.txt
```

Replacing -e with -i did the trick for me. Thank you to all for helping me out.